# jQuery time interval click limitation

Tags: jquery

I need to work on a issue which is troubling our platform. There is this report page on the product web site and a user can go and generate reports. The report might be too big to be generated and takes like few minutes. Some users are impatience and click the generate buttons many times. I was wondering is it possible to set a time on the button, that is, when someone clicks the generate report button, the page does not let them to press again for say another 5 minutes. The more interesting scenario would be, store something in cookie or something to still stop them from clicking even if they refresh the page.

I'd be grateful if you could give me some good ideas or examples on this matter as I am not a pro at jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you could use local storage to set a timestamp, and set the disabled property easily with jQuery.

**To disable on click**:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prop('disabled', true);
    localStorage.myButtonEnableAt = new Date().getTime() + 30000;

    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.prop('disabled', false);
        localStorage.myButtonEnableAt = null;
    }, 30000);
});
```

**On page load, check the state**:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
if (localStorage.myButtonEnableAt > now ) {
    $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#myButton').prop('disabled', false);
        localStorage.myButtonEnableAt = null;
    }, localStorage.myButtonEnableAt - now);
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/36JrM/ -- changed to 10 second disable for a faster demo. Click the button. After 5 seconds, refresh the page and it'll enable after 5 more seconds as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple case, you could disable the button:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Although a better solution would be to display a progress indicator (or at least a spinning wheel) to tell the user that *something* is being done. You could also have a fake progress bar that slowly increments for seven minutes.

The real problem is that the users aren't getting any feedback, so they press buttons to get some sort of feedback from you. Disabling the button and not letting them re-submit it might make them frustrated, but I bet that giving *any* sort of progress to your users will make them happy.

Answer (score 0):

For forms I usually do something like this, so it handles any kind of submitting, not just button click.

```
$('form').bind('submit',function(e){
    var $form = $(this);

    if ($form.data('submitted') === true){
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
    else {
        $form.data('submitted', true);
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        $form.data('submitted', false);
    }, 30000);
});
```

For buttons only you can use the `.prop('disabled', true)` as mentioned in other answers.